# In my postback event handler, why is my type.substring(0, 11) === 'owned_lists' not working even though my conosole.log shows that it should?

Tags: json, node.js, api, express

Sometimes a postback will happen in my app.  I have a handler for when I get a postback. It checks what type the postback is and then does something.
There are two "types" of postbacks: `'owned_lists'` and `'subscribed_lists'`.
Below is my handler code.

```
   const handleReceivePostback = (event) => {
  /**
   * The 'payload' param is a developer-defined field which is
   * set in a postbackbutton for Structured Messages.
   *
   * In this case we've defined our payload in our postback
   * actions to be a string that represents a JSON object
   * containing `type` and `data` properties. EG:
   */
  const type = event.postback.payload;
  const senderId = event.sender.id;

  // Perform an action based on the type of payload received.
  if (type.substring(0, 11) === 'owned_lists') {
    sendOwnedLists(senderId, type);
  } else if (type.substring(0, 16) === 'subscribed_lists') {
    sendSharedLists(senderId, type);
  } else if (type.substring(0, 11) === 'get_started') {
    sendApi.sendWelcomeMessage(senderId);
    return;
  }
  // eslint-enable camelcase

  sendApi.sendMessage(senderId, `Unknown Postback called: ${type}`);
};
```

When a postback of type 'owned_lists' goes through this handler, it doesnt trigger true for the first if clause.

My console.log shows

```
messageDataArray: 
   [ { recipient: [Object],
       message: 'Unknown Postback called: owned_lists' },
     { recipient: [Object], sender_action: 'typing_off' } ],
```

Even though the `type` is clearly `owned_lists` according to console.log, it still does not trigger the if clause. Why? This is particularly strange to me because when the type is `subscribed_lists` or `owned_lists` it manages to go to its appropriate if clause code.

I'm not sure whether this is part of the bug, but below is the code for how my subscribed_lists and owned_lists type postbacks are triggered is below. I have a menu with 2 buttons.

```
const persistentMenu = () => {
  api.callThreadAPI(
    {
      setting_type: 'call_to_actions',
      thread_state: 'existing_thread',
      call_to_actions: [
        {
          type: 'postback',
          title: 'My Group Orders',
          payload: 'owned_lists',
        },
        {
          type: 'postback',
          title: 'Shared With Me',
          payload: 'subscribed_lists',
        },
      ],
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Try to log...type...

Comment: why should i try that if i end up getting message: 'Unknown Postback called: owned_lists'  in my console anyways where owned_lists is ${type}?

Comment: Wild guess: `sendOwnedLists()` does nothing, so you *think* it does not go into the desired `if` clause, but it does?

Comment: @wscourge sendApi.sendMessage(senderId, `Unknown Postback called: ${type}`) only gets called if it does not go to the desired if clause, so i dont think that's what happens. my sendOwnedLists() code is `const sendOwnedLists = (senderId, type) => {
  Lists.getOwnedForUser(senderId)
    .then((lists) => {
      sendApi.sendLists(senderId, type, lists, Number(type.substring(19)));
    });
};`

Comment: Just place `console.log()` in each of the `if` clauses, and also try `console.log(type.substring(0, 11) === 'owned_lists')` to see that `false` and be 100% sure it is not what I'm suggesting. Also, do `console.log(type.substring(0, 11), typeof type.substring(0, 11))`.

Comment: ok thanks, ill try that

Comment: @qaz if `type` is `'Unknown Postback called: owned_lists'` then how can `.substring(0, 11)` return `'owned_lists'`?